# Why doesn't RuleDelayed hold Unevaluated?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The *Mathematica*'s evaluator generally holds (or restores?) `Head`s `Unevaluated` of expressions supplied as arguments for `Symbol`s:

```
In[1]:= f[s, Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

Out[2]= f[s, Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

In[5]:= Trace[f[s,Unevaluated[1+1]],TraceOriginal->True]

Out[5]= {f[s,Unevaluated[1+1]],{f},{s},f[s,1+1],f[s,Unevaluated[1+1]]}
```

But it is not true for `RuleDelayed`. Moreover, *any* number of `Unevaluated` wrappers are stripped in the case of `RuleDelayed`:

```
In[1]:= Attributes@RuleDelayed
RuleDelayed[s, Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
RuleDelayed[s, Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
RuleDelayed[s, Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
RuleDelayed[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1], 1 + 1]

Out[1]= {HoldRest, Protected, SequenceHold}

Out[2]= s :> 1 + 1

Out[3]= s :> 1 + 1

Out[4]= s :> 1 + 1

Out[5]= 2 :> 1 + 1
```

Why does the evaluator strip *any* number of `Unevaluated` wrappers in the case of `RuleDelayed`? For which purposes is it useful? Is it possible to simulate such behavior for an arbitrary `Symbol` (`f`, for example)?

---

It is also not clear why the `Trace` shows more complicated picture for `RuleDelayed` than for `f`:

```
In[2]:= Trace[RuleDelayed[s,1+1],TraceOriginal->True]
Out[2]= {s:>1+1,{RuleDelayed},{s},s:>1+1,s:>1+1,{RuleDelayed},{s},s:>1+1}
```

It looks like `RuleDelayed` is evaluated twice...

Comment: If it doesn't remove it ... wouldn't it result in two nested `Unevaluated`?

Comment: @belisarius For `f[s, Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` everything is simple. From where we would get two nested `Unevaluated`?

Comment: @Sasha answered before me (and better)

Comment: "But it is not true for RuleDelayed despite it even has the HoldRest attribute" - as we all discussed many times, `HoldRest` is (almost) irrelevant - it just puts the head in the position to decide what to do with the original expression passed to it. And if the standard semantics of `Unevaluted` is always enforced, evaluator itself is also irrelevant. The real question IMO (I may be wrong of course) is why `RuleDelayed` behaves the way it does, or, may be, why the exception was made for it regarding the evaluator behavior, if it still turns out that evaluator is the culprit.

Comment: @Leonid It seems that I am understanding the term "evaluator" in more broad sense than you use it. Are you draw a demarcation line between working of function attributes and the working of the evaluator? Do you mean by "evaluator" only application of rules? What about pure functions? I feel the terms "evaluation" and "evaluator" a bit vague.

Comment: @Leonid Probably I should create a separate question on the use of these terms but such question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I consider function attributes to be indeed related to evaluator. What I was saying was that attributes are irrelevant to the question, at least if you reformulate it as "why *any* number of `Unevaluated` wrappers are stripped by `RuleDelayed`".As I mentioned below in the comments, standard semantics of `Unevaluated` (which also is related to evaluator) can not explain stripping off more than one `Unevaluated` wrapper in a single evaluation, nor does it explain the re-evaluation upon stripping a single layer of `Unevaluated` - these must then be properties of the head in question (RuleDelayed)

Comment: @Leonid I have reformulated the question according to your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Unevaluated` gets stripped when it occurs as the outermost wrapper in a rule. This is how `Unevaluated` works, i.e. `Unevaluated` is not a regular symbol which evaluates anything. It is a token. Compare

```
In[8]:= f[s_] := g[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

In[9]:= DownValues[f]

Out[9]= {HoldPattern[f[s_]] :> g[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]}
```

And

```
In[10]:= f[s_] := Unevaluated[1 + 1]

In[11]:= DownValues[f]

Out[11]= {HoldPattern[f[s_]] :> 1 + 1}
```

Because evaluator is recursive, it suffices to get rid of `Unevaluated` eventually.

---

**EDIT** Expanding answer per Alexey's remark:

`Unevaluated` is an inert symbol, a token which is recognized by evaluator and acted upon within rules. For this reason `Unevaluated[1+1]` is unchanged, as well as `f[1,Unevaluated[1+1]]`. When `RuleDelayed[s,Unevaluated[1+1]]` is evaluated, `Unevaluated` is stripped, and then the entire `RuleDelayed` expression is reevaluated per evaluation principles.

---

**EDIT 2** This is a condensed outcome of discussions on the cause for reevaluation

> the implementation details of `RuleDelayed` cause repeated evaluations, which results in eventual stripping of the Unevaluated. In comments below my answer, I provided an example of another command which causes double evaluation for precisely the same reason. This happens because expression undergoes validation, and once validated, it is stamped with a certain valid flag. Setting the valid flag initiates reevaluation sequence. This is happening until expression no longer changes.

Similar effect occurs for other expression that require validation, like `Root` object:

```
In[41]:= Root[#1^6 + #1 - 1 & , 1]; Trace[Root[#1^6 + #1 - 1 & , 1], 
 TraceOriginal -> True]

Out[41]= {
 HoldForm[Root[#1^6 + #1 - 1 & , 1]], {HoldForm[Root]}, 
   {HoldForm[#1^6 + #1 - 1 & ], {HoldForm[Function]}, 
  HoldForm[#1^6 + #1 - 1 & ]}, 
   {HoldForm[1]}, 
  HoldForm[Root[#1^6 + #1 - 1 & , 1]],    <-- here the root had been 
                                              stamped valid, and reevaluated
   HoldForm[Root[-1 + #1 + #1^6 & , 1]]   <-- evaluation was trivial.
```

}

Comment: But for what it is done? In which cases it is useful? See also addition at the bottom of the question: why `Trace` shows that `RuleDelayed` is evaluated twice?

Comment: @Alexey Please see the edit with the answer to your question.

Comment: Is this evaluation principle related only to evaluation of a rule? Or there are other cases when the entire expression is re-evaluated again? In simple cases with other symbols it does not happen: `Trace[ff[s,1+1],TraceOriginal->True]` shows only one evaluation of the head `ff` while `Trace[RuleDelayed[s,1+1],TraceOriginal->True]` shows that the symbol `RuleDelayed` is evaluated twice.

Comment: @Alexey Even `Trace[RuleDelayed[s, 1], TraceOriginal -> True]` shows double evaluation. This probably has to do with certain precomputations performed for the (trivial) pattern used in the rule. The result of the precomputation is then "associated" with the rule. This association changes the expression, and thus causes the evaluation. You may see this for other expressions as well. Consider `Root[#^6 + # - 1 &, 1]; Trace[Root[#^6 + # - 1 &, 1], TraceOriginal -> True]`. The first `Root` is to force Mathematica package loading.

Comment: At present (v13), `Root` does not have any more this special behavior (and no package is loaded).

Answer (score 9):

This answer should be considered as complementary to @Sasha's answer. I believe that this is a subtle topic that can benefit from explanations from several viewpoints.

#### Why the question is non-trivial

I want to stress that the behavior in question is not typical, in the sense that it is not how most heads behave in Mathematica, and it can not be explained based just on the general principles of evaluation (in particular mechanics of `Unevaluated` stripping), without resorting to implementation details of a particular head with such behavior (`RuleDelayed` here). Consider some general head with a `HoldRest` attribute:

```
In[185]:= SetAttributes[h, HoldRest];
h[1, Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]

Out[186]= h[1, Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]
```

while

```
In[209]:= 1:>Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]

Out[209]= 1:>1+1
```

#### Some details on stripping off the `Unevaluated` wrapers

This is based on discussions in the book of David Wagner "Power programming in Mathematica - the kernel", the WRI technical report by David Withoff named "Mathematica internals", and my own experiences.

Here is a very simplified  picture of evaluation. Mathematica evaluates expressions recursively, first going "down" from "branches" (expressions) to "sub-branches" (sub-expressions) and leaves (atoms), and then going "up". On the way "down", heads of (sub) expressions are evaluated, and then parts. Those parts that have the head `Unevaluated`, are not evaluated further (in the sense that the evaluator is not called recursively on them), while `Unevaluated` gets stripped and it is marked that this has been done. On the way "up", it is considered that parts have been already evaluated. There are a number of steps including sequences splicing, evaluations related to attributes like `Flat`, `Orderless` etc. Then, rules for the head where evaluation is currently, are applied, user-defined and built-in (`UpValues`, `DownValues`, `SubValues`). Finally, and this is what is important for this discussion, the `Unevaluated` wrappers are restored for those parts of expression where no applicable rules were found. This is why, for an undefined function `f`, we have:

```
In[188]:= ClearAll[f];
f[Unevaluated[1+1]]

Out[189]= f[Unevaluated[1+1]]
```

One can confirm that `Unevaluated` wrappers were stripped and then restored, by using `Trace` with the `TraceOriginal` option set to `True`:

```
In[190]:= Trace[f[Unevaluated[1+1]],TraceOriginal->True]

Out[190]= {f[Unevaluated[1+1]],{f},f[1+1],f[Unevaluated[1+1]]}
```

What happens when there are some rules defined for `f`? The answer is that each rule application strips off one layer of `Unevaluated`. Here is an example:

```
In[204]:= 
f[x_]:=Hold[x]; 
g[x_]:=f[x];
{f[Unevaluated[1+1]],g[Unevaluated[1+1]]}
{f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]],g[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]]}
{f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]], g[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]]}

Out[206]= {Hold[1+1],Hold[2]}
Out[207]= {Hold[Unevaluated[1+1]],Hold[1+1]}
Out[208]= {Hold[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1+1]]],Hold[Unevaluated[1+1]]}
```

If one knew in exactly how many evaluations will a given part of expression particiapte, one could in principle wrap that part in that many layers of `Unevaluated` to prevent its evaluation. This information is however impossible to have generally, and `Unevaluated` should not be used as a persistent holding wrapper - this is what `Hold` is for. But this analysis may make it clearer that, in order to trip *any* number of evaluations, the head which does it must have non-trivial rules defined for it. In other words, normally, the part of evaluation process consisting of stripping off a layer of `Unevaluated` does not (by itself, "on the way down the expression"), induce its re-evaluation - this can happen only on the way "up", due to some rules defined for that head. The conclusion is that the observed behavior of `RuleDelayed` can only be explained by looking at the implementation details for `RuleDelayed`, general considerations are not enough.

#### An illustration: simulating the behavior of `RuleDelayed`

I will now illustrate this and also answer the part of the original question regarding the simulation of this behavior. As far as I can tell, the following code fully simulates the behavior of `RuleDelayed` regarding stripping off `Unevaluated` wrappers:

```
ClearAll[rd];
SetAttributes[rd, {HoldAllComplete, SequenceHold}];
rd[lhs_, Verbatim[Unevaluated][rhs_]] /;
   Head[Unevaluated[rhs]] =!= Unevaluated := Append[rd[lhs], Unevaluated[rhs]];
rd[lhs_, Verbatim[Unevaluated][rhs_]] := rd @@ {lhs, rhs};
rd[lhs_, rhs_] /; Hold[lhs] =!= Hold[Evaluate[lhs]] := Prepend[rd[rhs], lhs];
```

(it may not be free of some evaluation leaks for other heads, but that's besides the point. Also, I was not able to make it `HoldRest`, like `RuleDelayed` - I had to use `HoldAllComplete` for this construction to work). You can check:

```
In[173]:= 
a=1;
rd[a,Unevaluated[1+1]]
rd[a,Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]]
rd[a,Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1+1]]

Out[174]= rd[1,1+1]
Out[175]= rd[1,1+1]
Out[176]= rd[1,1+1]
```

This indirectly supports my arguments that it may be the `RuleDelayed` implementation, rather than the evaluator, responsible for this effect (although, not knowing for sure, I can only guess. Also, `RuleDeleayed` is fundamental enough that this exceptional behavior could have been wired into the evaluator)

**EDIT**

To further strengthen the analogy, here are the results of tracing:

```
In[183]:= 
DeleteCases[Trace[rd[s,Unevaluated[1+1]],TraceOriginal->True],
    x_/;!FreeQ[x,Head|Hold|Append|HoldPattern[rd[_]]]]

Out[183]= {rd[s,Unevaluated[1+1]],{rd},rd[s,Unevaluated[1+1]],
    rd[s,1+1],{rd},rd[s,1+1],rd[s,1+1]}

In[184]:= Trace[RuleDelayed[s,Unevaluated[1+1]],TraceOriginal->True]

Out[184]= {s:>Unevaluated[1+1],{RuleDelayed},{s},s:>1+1,s:>1+1,{RuleDelayed},{s},s:>1+1}
```

The tracing results are very similar. I used `DeleteCases` to filter out intermediate evaluations for `rd`. The differences are due to the `HoldAllComplete` attribute of `rd` vs. `HoldRest` of `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: Your function definitions has inconsistence regarding evaluation of the `lhs`: the first definition holds it while the second evaluates.

Comment: @Alexey Good catch! I updated the code and the test examples, to address this issue.

Comment: @Leonid I agree, and this is also what I said, the implementation details of `RuleDelayed` cause repeated evaluations, which results in eventual stripping of the `Unevaluated`. In comments below my answer, I provided an example of another command which causes double evaluation for precisely the same reason.  This happens because expression undergoes validation, and once validated, it is stamped with a certain valid flag. Setting the valid flag initiates reevaluation sequence. This is happening until expression no longer changes.

Comment: @Sasha I see now. It was not clear for me from your answer that you treat the situation as specific for `RuleDelayed` and based on its implementation internal details, otherwise I would not make those comments. It looked like you were explaining this using only the general semantics of `Unevaluated`. I thought that general arguments are not enough and pointed this out. Sorry if I misunderstood. Could you edit your post to reflect this? I'd remove those comments then, perhaps partly incorporating them into my answer to complement yours.

Comment: @Leonid Thank you for the analysis! But new version of your function  does not evaluate the `lhs` with head `Evaluate` with simple `rhs`: `rd[Evaluate[1 + 1], 1 + 1]`.

Comment: @Alexey It wasn't my goal to make a complete imitation, but you can change the last definition to `rd[lhs_, rhs_] := With[{evalLhs = lhs},
Prepend[rd[rhs],lhs] /; HoldComplete[lhs] =!= HoldComplete[evalLhs]];` to avoid this flaw. This will also avoid another flaw of the current version - for general l.h.s., it is evaluated twice, which is bad - the l.h.s. may contain side effects. The new version evaluates l.h.s. only once.

Comment: @Leonid Good idea to use `With`! But `Prepend[rd[rhs],lhs]` results in double evaluation of `rd`. I avoid this using `Replace[Prepend[Hold[rhs],lhs], Hold :> rd, {1}, Heads -> True]`. But is there a better way?

Comment: @Alexey You can use `Prepend[Unevaluated[rd[rhs]], lhs]`, but since `rd` does not have rules for 1 argument, I don't see much point. I also don't think that forging the *exact* imitation of `RuleDelayed` with all bells and whistles is worth the effort - we already saw the main principle, realized that the effect is caused by specifics of `RuleDelayed`, and I think that is the main point.

Answer (score 4):

### Reproducing the behavior of RuleDelayed with user-defined function "rd"

Here is straightforward way to reproduce `RuleDelayed` evaluation behavior based on Sasha's description:

> <...> [Rule] expression undergoes validation,
>   and once validated, it is stamped with
>   a certain valid flag. Setting the
>   valid flag initiates reevaluation
>   sequence. This is happening until
>   expression no longer changes.

```
ClearAll[rd];
SetAttributes[rd, {HoldRest, SequenceHold}];
Options[rd] = {"Validated" -> None};
expr : rd[args__] /; ("Validated" /. Options[Unevaluated[rd]]) =!= 
   Hold[expr] := (Options[
    Unevaluated[rd]] = {"Validated" -> Hold[expr]}; rd[args])

In[6]:= rd[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1], 
 Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]

Out[6]= rd[2, 1 + 1]
```

We can compare the number of evaluations of the first argument for `rd` and `RuleDelayed`:

```
dummyFunction /; (++numberOfEvaluations; False) := Null;

In[36]:= numberOfEvaluations=0;
rd[dummyFunction,Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1+1]]];
numberOfEvaluations
numberOfEvaluations=0;
RuleDelayed[dummyFunction,Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1+1]]];
numberOfEvaluations
Out[38]= 4
Out[41]= 4
```

### Tracing rd and RuleDelayed

The following demonstrates that this version replicates the behavior of `RuleDelayed` almost exactly. The only difference is the last additional evaluation of the final expression `rd[2,1+1]` which involves condition check and gives no match. With using `rd` as the second argument of `Trace` this last evaluation is excluded automatically. In the case of `RuleDelayed` this last check cannot be caught by `Trace` since it does not go through the evaluator.

The code:

```
ClearAll[rd];
SetAttributes[rd, {HoldRest, SequenceHold}];
SetAttributes[returnLast, {HoldRest}]
SetAttributes[{NotValidatedQ, setValidatedFlag}, HoldAllComplete];
Options[rd] = {"Validated" -> None};
NotValidatedQ[expr_] := ("Validated" /. Options[Unevaluated[rd]]) =!= 
   Hold[expr];
setValidatedFlag[expr_] := 
  Options[Unevaluated[rd]] = {"Validated" -> Hold[expr]};
returnLast[first_, last_] := last;
expr : rd[args__] /; NotValidatedQ[expr] := 
 returnLast[setValidatedFlag[expr], rd[args]]
```

Comparison:

```
rdList = DeleteCases[
   Trace[rd[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1], 
     Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]], 
    TraceOriginal -> 
     True], ({HoldForm[(validatedQ | setValidatedFlag)[_]], ___} | 
     HoldForm[_returnLast] | {HoldForm[returnLast]})] /. 
  rd -> RuleDelayed

RuleDelayedList = 
 Trace[RuleDelayed[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1], 
   Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]], 
  TraceOriginal -> True]
```

[image: screenshot]

Tracing with using of the second argument of `Trace` shows exact match:

```
In[52]:= rdList = 
  Trace[rd[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1], 
     Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]], rd, 
    TraceOriginal -> True] /. {HoldForm[_returnLast] -> Sequence[], 
    rd -> RuleDelayed};
RuleDelayedList = 
  Trace[RuleDelayed[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1], 
    Unevaluated@Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]], RuleDelayed, 
   TraceOriginal -> True];

rdList === RuleDelayedList

Out[54]= True
```