# Question on nested Unevaluated

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267143/why-ruledelayed-does-not-hold-unevaluated/6274032#6274032) to simulate the evaluation behavior of `RuleDelayed` I faced unexpected behavior of nested `Unevaluated`. Consider:

```
In[1]:= f[Verbatim[Unevaluated][expr_]] := f[expr]
f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]
f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

Out[2]= f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

Out[3]= f[2]

Out[4]= f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]

Out[5]= f[2]
```

One can see that only even number of nested `Unevaluated` wrappers are completely removed. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Trace to see why:

```
In[1]:= f[Verbatim[Unevaluated][expr_]]:=f[expr]

In[2]:= f[Unevaluated[1+1]]//Trace
Out[2]= {f[1+1],f[Unevaluated[1+1]]}
```

1. Due to the defining special property of the `Unevaluated` language construct, `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` evaluates just like `f[1 + 1]` except the `1 + 1` is left unevaluated.
2. `f[1 + 1]` does not match the definition you gave for `f`.
3. Therefore `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` remains unevaluated.

Whereas:

```
In[3]:= f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]] // Trace
Out[3]= {f[Unevaluated[1+1]],f[1+1],{1+1,2},f[2]}
```

1. Due to the defining special property of the `Unevaluated` language construct, `f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` evaluates just like `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` except the `Unevaluated[1 + 1]` is left unevaluated.
2. `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` matches the definition you gave for `f`, and evaluates to `f[1 + 1]`.
3. Therefore `f[Unevaluated@Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` evaluates to `f[2]`.

Comment: Wow I literally beat you to the answer by seconds =)

Comment: Yeah! Nice coincidence for an hour old question. I like your answer better overall.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you! Both answers are great and complement each other, but your explanation in the form of a sequence of decisions taken by the evaluator is more schematic and easier to remember. So I accept your answer.

Answer (score 9):

The key is that, effectively, one layer of [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html) is removed before the expression is pattern-matched. From the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html):

> `f[Unevaluated[expr]]` effectively works
>   by temporarily setting attributes so
>   that `f` holds its argument unevaluated,
>   then evaluating `f[expr]`.

Thus, in the first case, `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` is evaluated as `f[1 + 1]`, but remaining *unevaluated* during pattern matching even though `f` lacks `Hold*` attributes, and since nothing matches `f[1 + 1]`, the *original* expression (pre-pattern-matching) is returned unevaluated.

In the second case, `f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]` evaluates as `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` in the pattern-matcher, which *does* match a pattern for `f`, and then `f[1 + 1]` is evaluated recursively, and thus you get `f[2]`.

In the third case, `f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]` evaluates as `f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]`, matches, and recursively evaluates as `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]`, and we're back to the first case.

In the fourth case, `f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]]` matches on `f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]]`, recursively evaluates `f[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]]`, and we're back to the second case.

HTH!